# No device drivers and windows boot loader available

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers

None my other devices drivers are available. So I can connect to no devices: USB ports, or WiFi, or ethernet. I already tried to. And this device has no Bluetooth.

[No device driver warning photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HowdE.jpg)

My laptop is Dell Inc. Inspiron 15-3567 x64 based PC. Os is windows 7 ultimate.

Another Problem:
I have no windows boot loader. I have to load from Internal HDD with legacy secure boot off option.

Comment: Windows 7 doesn’t support Secure Boot. So you having to disable Secure Boot in order to boot Windows 7 is expected, if that’s not acceptable, don’t use Windows 7

Comment: I would says, as always, don't use Windows 7, period. Your laptop is perfectly capable of running any modern Linux and even Windows 10 but that has an year of support left.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 is long out of support and basically dead.

Something has happened to the operating system and possibly the hardware.

You cannot any long install Windows 7 and update / patch it. That ability has been discontinued.

Download the Windows 10 ISO from the Microsoft Media Creation link.

[MCL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d)

Make a bootable USB that you can start from.

Find the Manufacturer's hardware diagnostic app, test the hardware, and assuming that is OK, install Windows 10.

You may wish to recover any data by putting the drive in a carrier and getting the data on another machine. You may be able to get the data using the ISO you created before it starts installing and copying data to a USB hard drive.

Based on your post, you may need to try a new drive in any event.   And it the computer is old enough, perhaps time to replace it.

Comment: Yes, the computer is old. I I only need it for basic purposes like word processing etc. I have no data in this computer as well. And I only recently added windows 7 since windows 10 lagged a lot for some reason and windows 10 is overkill for my purposes.

Comment: If you do decide to replace, Windows 11 is now the main OS.

Comment: @Alex Windows 7 is dangerous when online. If you don't want to cause issues to yourself and others DON'T user it, period. If the reason for not using Windows 10 is because "it lagged a lot" then 1. it wasn't correctly optimized as it should have been and 2. again, use Linux, any distro with a lightweight Desktop Environment will work better that any Windows.